# Can we solve a system of linear equations with singular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Given the system of equations $AX=B$ where $A$ is singular. Can one solve for $X$ in this case? Consider the following example for illustratrion

$A = \begin{pmatrix}  0  &  a_3  & -a_2\\
                     -a_3  & 0  & a_1 \\
                       a_2  & -a_1  & 0 \end{pmatrix}$,

$X= \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y  \\ z \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2  \\ b_3 \end{pmatrix} $.

Edit: There was a typo in $A$.
How can one solve for $x,y,z$ in this case?

Comment: You can try using the standard approach of row-reduction of an augmented matrix. Remember, a solution $X$ to $AX=B$ exists if and only if the row-echelon form of the augmented matrix $\begin{bmatrix}A | B\end{bmatrix}$ has the right-hand column be **non-leading**. If $A$ is singular, then the row-echelon form will have some non-leading columns in the left-hand matrix. The variables corresponding to the non-leading columns can be set to *free parameters*, and then you can use back-substitution to solve for any remaining variables in terms of the free parameters.

Comment: the matrix$A$  need not be singular. The determinant is $a_1(a_2^2 - a_3^2)$

Comment: If $A$ is singular, $AX=B$ may or may not have a solution; if it does have a solution, the solution will be non-unique.

Comment: By "being able to solve" do you mean 1) the existence of an algorithm which gives you the set of all solutions of an equation or 2) the set of all solutions is non-empty?

Comment: @Mihail, thanks. I mean (2).

Answer (score 0):

If a matrix is singular it means that its determinant is zero.

If a determinant is zero it means some row/col is a linear combination of other rows/cols.

So, not all vectors ${x,y,z}$ can be expressed as a combination of the vectors that each row/col of the matrix represents (The matrix is a tranformation between bases).

In general you can not solve the system.

 But there are cases where the matrix is able to represent some group of vectors. Using a submatrix obtained by eliminating the linear combination, and that submatrix not being singular.

Suppose you eliminated the third column. Then, you can still obtain $x,y$, but $z$ coordinate will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In general we cannot solve the system $Ax=b$ for a singular matrix $A$ and given $b$.
In your example, take $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$. Then we cannot solve the system $Ax=b$, except for $b=0$.

Solutions of your example.

Case 1: $a_1=0$.

Case 1a: $a_2\neq 0$. Then we have $x=b_3/a_2$. Substitute this into the other equations.

Case 1b: $a_1=a_2=0$.  We have no solution for $b_3\neq 0$.

Case 2: $a_1\neq 0$. Then $y=(b_3-a_2x)/a_1$. Subsitute this into the other equations.

Comment: why did you choose the first combination $a_1 (a_2^2 - a_3^2)$?

Comment: But the determinant comes out to be $a_1a_2a_3 - a_1 a_2 a_3 = 0$.

Comment: Ah, this is different. Then we have one case less, even better.

Answer (score 0):

Here the approach using the linear transformations could be useful, i.e. use matrices 3×3 and linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^3$   to $\mathbb{R}^3$ interchangebly :

> For every noninvertible $A$ there is a vector $b$ s.t. $AX=b$ has no solutions

Indeed, $A$ has a rank less than 3 so it cannot be surjective onto  $\mathbb{R}^3$ . Pick any $b$ outside the image of $A$ and we are done.

Comment: could you explain this in light of the given example?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of $ A x = b $ (if they exist) will be of the form

$ x = \displaystyle x_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i v_i $

where the ${v_i}$ form a basis of the null space of $A$.  i.e. $A v_i = 0$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots , k $. ($k$ is the nullity of $A$).

And, $x_0$ is any solution of $A x = b$, to find it, reduce the augmented matrix $[A | b ]$ to Reduced-Row Echelon Form.  If there is a row that is all zeroes except a non-zero entry at the end, then the system is inconsistent, and there is no solution.  Otherwise, the system is consistent, and $x_0$ can be determined by solving the reduced system with the arbitrary variables all set to $0$.  Determine the leading $1$'s in the reduced matrix.  The columns with no leading $1$'s correspond to the arbitrary variables.  Set these arbitrary variables to $0$, and solve the reduced system.

For example, suppose you have the following system

$ A x = b $

where

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -2 && 5 \\ 4 && 3 && -2 \\ -1 && 1 && -3 \end{bmatrix},\hspace{20pt} b = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 18 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $

Here, $A$ is singular, so to solve the system, form the augmented matrix, and reduce,

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -2 && 5 && - 1 \\ 4 && 3 && -2 && 18 \\ -1 && 1 && -3 && -1 \end{bmatrix} $

After the first iteration, we get

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -2 && 5 && -1 \\ 0 && 11 && - 22 && 22 \\ 0 && -1 && 2 && -2 \end{bmatrix} $

Switching rows $(2)$ and $(3)$ gives

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -2 && 5 && -1 \\ 0 && -1 && 2 && -2 \\ 0 && 11 && - 22 && 22  \end{bmatrix} $

Eliminating the entries in the second column, we obtain,

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 1 && 3 \\ 0 && 1 && -2 && 2 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0  \end{bmatrix} $

This is the reduced-row echelon form of the augmented matrix.  As can be seen, the system is consistent.  The column with no leading $1$ is the third column.  So we set $z=0$ and solve the remaining system.

We immediately get $ x = 3 $ , $ y = 2 $.  Hence,

$ x_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Now, since we have one arbitrary variable, which is $z$, we want to find the corresponding $v$, by setting the last column to zero and solving

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && -2 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0  \end{bmatrix} $

If we set $z = t$, where $ t \in \mathbb{R} $, then from the first and second rows, we get

$ x = -t $

$ y = 2 t $

Hence the solution of the homogenized system is

$ v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

And therefore, the solution to our system is

$ x = x_0 + t v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + t \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

As another example, I'll take your system mentioned in the question.

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && a_3 && - a_2 \\ -a_3 && 0 && a_1 \\ a_2 && - a_1 && 0 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{20pt} b = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix} $

Again $A$ is singular, so we first form the augmented matrix

$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 && a_3 && - a_2 && b_1 \\ -a_3 && 0 && a_1 && b_2 \\ a_2 && - a_1 && 0 && b_3 \end{bmatrix} $

For simplicity assume $a_1 \ne 0 , a_2 \ne 0 , a_3 \ne 0 $, then divide the second and third rows by $(-a_3)$, and $a_2$, you get

$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 && a_3 && - a_2 && b_1 \\ 1 && 0 && -\dfrac{a_1}{a_3} && -\dfrac{b_2}{a_3} \\ 1 && - \dfrac{a_1}{a_2} && 0 && \dfrac{b_3}{a_2} \end{bmatrix} $

Switch the first and second rows:

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && -\dfrac{a_1}{a_3} && -\dfrac{b_2}{a_3} \\ 0 && a_3 && - a_2 && b_1 \\  1 && - \dfrac{a_1}{a_2} && 0 && \dfrac{b_3}{a_2} \end{bmatrix} $

Eliminate the leading $1$ in the third row, and divide the second row by $ a_3 $, this leads to,

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && -\dfrac{a_1}{a_3} && -\dfrac{b_2}{a_3} \\ 0 && 1 && - \dfrac{a_2}{a_3} && \dfrac{b_1}{a_3} \\  0 && - \dfrac{a_1}{a_2} && \dfrac{a_1}{a_3} && \dfrac{b_3}{a_2} + \dfrac{b_2}{a_3} \end{bmatrix} $

Eliminate the leading entry in the third row, this gives us,

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && -\dfrac{a_1}{a_3} && -\dfrac{b_2}{a_3} \\ 0 && 1 && - \dfrac{a_2}{a_3} && \dfrac{b_1}{a_3} \\  0 && 0 && 0 && \dfrac{a_1 b_1}{a_2 a_3} + \dfrac{b_3}{a_2} + \dfrac{b_2}{a_3} \end{bmatrix} $

And we're done.

For this system to have a solution, we must have

$ \dfrac{a_1 b_1}{a_2 a_3} + \dfrac{b_3}{a_2} + \dfrac{b_2}{a_3} = 0 $

The left hand side of this equation is just

$ \dfrac{ a_1 b_1 + b_2 a_2 + b_3 a_3 }{a_2 a_3 } $

And this will be zero if and only if $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ is orthogonal to $(b_1, b_2, b_3) $

Assuming this to be the case, then we now have

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && -\dfrac{a_1}{a_3} && -\dfrac{b_2}{a_3} \\ 0 && 1 && - \dfrac{a_2}{a_3} && \dfrac{b_1}{a_3} \end{bmatrix} $

By setting the third variable to zero, we get as a particular solution

$ x_0 = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{b_2}{a_3} \\ \dfrac{b_1}{a_3} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Now to find $v_1$ the solution to the homogenized system, take the last column to be zero, and solve, you get

$ v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{a_1}{a_3} \\ \dfrac{a_2}{a_3} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Since $t$ is arbitrary, we can simplify things, by multiplying this vector by $a_3$, and take

$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix} $

Hence, the general solution is

$ x = x_0 + t v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{b_2}{a_3} \\ \dfrac{b_1}{a_3} \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} + t \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix} $

To verify this is indeed a valid solution, remember,

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && a_3 && - a_2 \\ -a_3 && 0 && a_1 \\ a_2 && - a_1 && 0 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{20pt} b = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix} $

Caclulate $Ax$:

$A x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && a_3 && - a_2 \\ -a_3 && 0 && a_1 \\ a_2 && - a_1 && 0 \end{bmatrix} \left(  \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{b_2}{a_3} \\ \dfrac{b_1}{a_3} \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} + t \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \dfrac{-a_2 b_2  -a_1 b_1}{a_3} \end{bmatrix}$

Since we've assumed that $ a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3 = 0 $ then the above simplifies to

$ A x = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix} = b $

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

Notice that in our particular case, $$A X = X \times {\bf a}, \qquad 
\textrm{where} \qquad {\bf a} := \pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_3} .$$
So, if $X$ satisfes $A X = B$, that is, if $X \times {\bf a} = B$, then $B$ is orthogonal to both $X$ and ${\bf a}$. Thus:

- If ${\bf a} \cdot B \neq 0$, then there is no solution $X$.
- If ${\bf a} \neq {\bf 0}$, then $\operatorname{rank} A = 2$, so $A X = B$ has a solution if and only if ${\bf a} \cdot B = 0$. In that case, since $A {\bf a} = {\bf 0}$, we have $\ker A = \operatorname{span}\{{\bf a}\}$, hence the solution space is $\{X_0 + \lambda {\bf a} : \lambda \in \Bbb F\}$.
- If ${\bf a} = {\bf 0}$, then the equation becomes $B = {\bf 0}$, which has solution space $\Bbb F^3$ if $B = {\bf 0}$ and no solutions otherwise.